# Probablity of winning a bet

Tags: probability, random-variables

> **Question :** Three balls are to be randomly selected without replacement from an urn containing $20$ balls numbered $1$ through $20$. If we bet that at least one of the balls that are drawn hasa number as large as or larger than $17$, what is the probability that we win the bet?

I am sorry that I neither have any approach nor any solution. I am not getting question at all. I am completely new to random variable concept, thus will need some help initially.
Please help me out.

P.S - This is not a homework question.

Comment: This might help you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urn_problem
You don't even need random variables here. Just think about all the cases that can happen and what their probabilities are.

Comment: Can you find the probability that you will **not** win?

Comment: @drhab it will be many .we have to calculate each for Ball numbered from $1$ to $16$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $i=1,2,3$ let $E_i$ denote the event that the number of the $i$-th drawn ball is smaller than $17$.

Then you are looking for: $$1-P(E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3)=1-P(E_1)P(E_2\mid E_1)P(E_3\mid E_1\cap E_2)=1-\frac{16}{20}\frac{15}{19}\frac{14}{18}$$

Comment: thanks a lot sir :)

Answer (score 2):

Let us simplify the game a little bit. Suppose that balls $1,\ldots,16$ are red and $17,\ldots,20$ are green. We win if we draw a green ball. The distribution of green balls among the three drawn balls is [hypergeometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) since we are drawing without replacement. The probability to get $k$ green balls in the sample is given by
$$
\frac{{4\choose k}{16\choose 3-k}}{{20\choose 3}}
$$
for $k=0,1,2,3$. Hence, the probability that we win is given by
$$
\frac{{4\choose 1}{16\choose 2}}{{20\choose 3}}+\frac{{4\choose 2}{16\choose 1}}{{20\choose 3}}+\frac{{4\choose 3}{16\choose 0}}{{20\choose 3}}\approx0.5088.
$$

Comment: But the numbered balls are not identical though...

Comment: thanks a lot sir :)

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat You can keep the numbers if you want, just colour the balls $17,\ldots,20$ green.

Comment: Identity is not necessary; they are equivalent and that is sufficient to use the approach in this answer. @KarnWatcharasupat

Comment: Oh I see. The order has already been taken care of. Sorry I'm not used to hypergeometric distribution.

Answer (score 1):

First, find out probability of not winning then 1-that.

Total no of outcomes(A) : 20C1 x 19C1 x 18C1

Favourable outcomes for not winning(B) : 16C1 x 15C1 x 14C1 (Selecting balls numbered <17)

So the probability of not winning(C) : B/A = 28/57

Thus, required probability : 1 - C = 1 - (28/57) = **29/57**.

Answer (score 0):

We need to find the probability of not getting a ball above $17$ first. In the urn, there are $4$ balls that are equal or larger than $17$ ($17,18,19,20$). Since there are $20$ balls, there are $20-4=16$ number of balls that are below $17$ in the urn. That means there is a $\frac{16}{20}$ chance that the first ball is less than $17$, $\frac{16-1}{20-1}$ chance that the second ball is less than $17$ provided the first ball is below $17$, and $\frac{16-2}{20-2}$ chance that the third ball is below $17$ provided the first two are below $17$. This gives us:
$$\frac{16}{20}\cdot\frac{16-1}{20-1}\cdot\frac{16-2}{20-2}$$
$$=\frac{16}{20}\cdot\frac{15}{19}\cdot\frac{14}{18}$$
$$=\frac{3360}{6840}$$
$$=\frac{28}{57}$$
Now, $1-\frac{28}{57}$=$\frac{29}{57}$ which is roughly $0.50877$.